# How to remove a VS Code user setting in settings.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating a new version of an extension in which I have modified some of the configuration setting names from the previous version. Suppose in the old version, a setting has the name `myextension.oldName` and in the new version this becomes `myextension.newName`.

I'm adding migration code to detect if the user has a setting with `myextension.oldName` set and if so, then set `myextension.newName` to the old value. However, I also want to delete `myextension.oldName` from the user's settings (`settings.json`), but I can't find a way to do this. I attempted setting the value of the `myextension.oldName` to `null` but this doesn't modify the value. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you set it to `undefined`, then it will be removed. Example:

```ts
vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().update('myExtension.mySetting', undefined, true);
```